# Como acceder a un dato especifico en VUE.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Recién estoy empezando con `Vue.js` y encontré un video tutorial de como implementarlo con `Laravel` lo cual me sirve.

Puedo acceder a los datos y mostrarlos como corresponde, pero:

```
<script>
    export default {
        // se retorna la informacion de un objeto
        data(){
          return{
            projects: [],
            form: new Form({
              id: '',
              name: '',
              initialDate:'',
              finalDate:'',
              active: ''
            })
          }
        },
        methods:{
          createProject(){
            this.form.post('api/project');
          },
          loadProjects(){
            axios.get("api/project").then(({ data }) => (this.projects = data));
          }
        },
        computed:{
          proActive: function(){
            return this.projects
          }
        },
        created(){
          this.loadProjects();
          Fire.$on('AfterCreate', () => {
            this.loadProjects();
          });
        }
    }
</script>
```

En estos videos trabajan de esta forma con `VUE.js`, no sé si es la mejor.

Lo que necesito es que el codigo desde la función **proActive** pueda acceder a la variable *active*, pero como se ve aqui abajo tengo escrito *return this.projects* y me trae todos los datos de esta forma:

```
{ "current_page": 1, "data": [ { "id": 1, "name": "XML", "initialDate": "2019-02-06", "finalDate": "2019-11-13", "active": 1, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 2, "name": "Fidelice", "initialDate": "2019-04-09", "finalDate": "2019-09-09", "active": 1, "created_at": "2019-04-09 22:26:19", "updated_at": "2019-04-09 22:26:19" } ], "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project?page=1", "from": 1, "last_page": 1, "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project?page=1", "next_page_url": null, "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project", "per_page": 10, "prev_page_url": null, "to": 2, "total": 2 }
```

Y si cambio esto a *return this.projects.data*, me devuelve:

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "XML", "initialDate": "2019-02-06", "finalDate": "2019-11-13", "active": 1, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 2, "name": "Fidelice", "initialDate": "2019-04-09", "finalDate": "2019-09-09", "active": 1, "created_at": "2019-04-09 22:26:19", "updated_at": "2019-04-09 22:26:19" } ]
```

Cómo llego a este dato? Porque mi idea es que ya teniendo el dato, que va de 0 a 4 poder poner un if y dependiendo del valor devolver una palabra.

algo como:

```
proActive: function(){
            if(this.projects.data.active == '1') return 'Activo'
          }
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la parte linda de programar, cuando encuentras la respuesta solo xD.

lo que hice fue crear un filtro con Vue.js

Dentro del código que se maneja en **app.js** tuve que poner:

```
Vue.filter('ActivePro', function(text){
  if(text == '0') return 'Inactivo'
  if(text == '1') return 'Activo'
  if(text == '2') return 'Pausado'
  if(text == '3') return 'Terminado'  
})
```

De esta forma a medida que se vaya poblando la tabla y dependiendo del valor este va a ir cambiando:

el código de mi tabla quedó así

```
<tr v-for="project in projects.data" :key="project.id">
   <td>{{ project.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ project.initialDate }}</td>
   <td>{{ project.finalDate }}</td>
   <td>{{ project.active | ActivePro }}</td>
   <td>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="far fa-edit green fa-lg iconom"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt red fa-lg iconom"></i>
      </a>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde del costado, de esta manera colaboras con la buena salud del sitio, efecto de % de preguntas resueltas :D